# Ошибка с Hyphenopoly

Tags: javascript, hyphenopoly

Я скачал Hyphenopoly и правильно подключил его. В JS указал, через `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...})`, что использование Hyphenopoly возможно лишь после загрузки всего HTML. Однако в консоли разработчика имеется ошибка:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Hyphenopoly is not defined
    at Hyphenopoly.js:54:8
    at Hyphenopoly.js:933:3
```

Hyphenopoly.js является файлом с архива Hyphenopoly, изменений в него я не вносил, ошибок я также не обнаружил.

Вот мой js-код, который запускает Hyphenopoly:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  Hyphenopoly.config({
    language: 'ru',
  }).then(() => {
  })
});
```

Comment: Как вы подключаете файл? Какая ссылка?

Comment: Так как я скачал его и он находится в папке проекта, то: <script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly.js"></script> (Ошибок нет и файл правильно определяется)

Comment: Да, файл находится в том же месте. Я только что проверил, все правильно (ибо тогда бы файл не открывался при нажатии на ссылку в <script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly.js"></script>)

Comment: Тогда я не уверен, может быть стоит попытаться слушатель повесить на `window`, а не `document`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было подключить дополнительные файлы в правильном порядке:

```
<script type="module" src="Ваш путь/hyphenopoly.module.js"></script>
<script src="Ваш путь/Hyphenopoly_Loader.js"></script>
<script src="Ваш путь/Hyphenopoly.js"></script>
```

Comment: Стоит добавить код который вы использовали для этого, думаю это поможет другим пользователям столкнувшимся с такой же проблемой.